# Resources to learn how Solana RPC API works?

Tags: api

I'm doing a project with Solana, I'm trying to learn how the RPC API works but it's very difficult because there isn't enough information on https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api Can you link to some resources on where can learn how this API works? Also is there is anyone here that wouldn't mind me asking them questions about how it works to talk in Discord or something like that?

Comment: what type of information are you looking for that isn't covered by the documentation that you've linked?

Comment: There are I think 100s of things, but one example would be in "sendTransaction" one of the parameters is "fully-signed Transaction, as encoded string" and I'm not sure how to do that and there aren't a few examples of this with it broken down to exactly how this works in depth.

Answer (score 3):

The Solana Cookbook is a good place to start. You mentioned sending transactions in a comment so here's the cookbook section about sending transactions https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol

Comment: Do you know of anything that teaches how the RPC API works instead of @solana/web3.js?